# A collection action with a view that looks like the index page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin controller which already has an index action. I want a custom action in this controller which renders a view that looks and functions similar to the default ActiveAdmin index view.

I have added a `collection_action` and added a corresponding view with the `.arb` Arbre extension. Then I used `table_for` in this view file, but what it gives is a plain table which does not have the sortable columns like on the Index page.

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: ActiveAdmin provides an extended `index_table_for` method that appears to at least give the ability to add a selectable column. I haven't used it myself, but it might be worth checking out. By default `index do` block appears to wrap everything in an `index_table_for` call. Reference: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, the IndexTableFor class, which is used in that `index_as_table.rb` file is defined locally only within that file. So, cannot access it from outside.